# Compojure + htmx get yields 403 forbidden

Tags: clojure, compojure

I have build a small hello world app with composure and htmx:

```
    (defroutes app-routes
  (GET "/" [] "
<html>
<script src=\"https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.9.8\"></script>
  <!-- have a button POST a click via AJAX -->
  <button hx-post=\"/clicked\" hx-swap=\"outerHTML\">
    Click Me
  </button>
</html>
")

  (POST "/clicked" [] "
<html>
<body>
Hell
<\body>
</html>
")
```

But when I click on the button, I get htmx.org@1.9.8:1 Response Status Error Code 403 from /clicked

Why is that?

Comment: If you check in the browser's DevTools Network panel, does the response have any body? Do you have any Ring middleware configured?

Comment: @EugenePakhomov I get url -X POST http://localhost:3000/clicked
<h1>Invalid anti-forgery token</h1>% in the bash

Comment: It can be disabled, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33132131/unable-to-complete-post-request-in-clojure

Comment: Well, seems like you gotta make htmx set the CSRF header, somehow. Or disable the CSRF protection if you don't need it for some reason.